# Not able to override the native hls behaviour on Safari, using videojs-contrib-hls plugin

Tags: video.js, http-live-streaming

I am trying to implement hls playback across different browsers using the video.js plugin (called, videojs-contrib-hls).  I'm not able to override the native hls behaviour on Safari, even after using the required 'overrideNative' parameter:

```
videojs.options.hls.overrideNative = true;
videojs.options.html5.nativeAudioTracks = false;
videojs.options.html5.nativeVideoTracks = false;
```

I am getting the following error on Safari:
"Overriding native HLS requires emulated tracks. See https://git.io/vMpjB"

Is there any other workaround to force videojs-contrib-hls over any native playback specially in Safari because with native safari hls we are getting few other issues and we want to make out player coherent across different browsers?
Also, please refer the following ticket:
https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/issues/1005

Answer (score 3):

**videojs-contrib-hls** is succeeded by **videojs-http-streaming**. VHS supports HLS and DASH and is built into video.js 7

When using videojs version >= 7 then you can override native hls player of safari  using a player object:

```
currentPlayer.ready(function() {
    this.src({                             
        src: 'https://example.com/hlsfile.m3u8',
        type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
        withCredentials: false,
    });
});
```

**Initialization:**

```
currentPlayer = videojs('playerid', {
html5: {
    nativeAudioTracks: false,
    nativeVideoTracks: false,
    hls: {
      overrideNative: true,
    }
  }
});
```

PS: Upvote if worked!

Comment: I implemented like this and it is working for all major browsers except in IOS's WKWebView. I am testing this on emulator. Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: hi Vaibhav. you can find solution for this problem in ios?

Comment: hi, any solution for ios?

Comment: Set below options

videojs.options.vhs.overrideNative = true;
videojs.options.html5.nativeAudioTracks = false;
videojs.options.html5.nativeVideoTracks = false;